# How does System.Convert fit OO conventions?

Tags: c#, oop

Aren't classes supposed to be called after objects and not actions? It just does not sit along with OO theory I learned.

One thought was that maybe since [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) holds only static methods then no instances of it are supposed to be created at all, which might make it an acceptable exception.

Comment: A functional programmer might tell you it's altogether ridiculous to make such a distinction between objects and actions, and "OO theory" is bogus if it makes such claims. Thank god there are none of these crazy guys around \*ducks\* [you've never seen me here]...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In C# you can't create methods outside classes or structs. So when you want to create utility methods, it's best to store them in a static class.

So i would say that there's nothing object oriented about a static class.

Comment: +1 there's nothing object oriented about a static class.

Comment: +1 in other programming languages this would be referred to as a `module`. Languages like Java and C# strive to make "everything an object", but in reality that just isn't the case - unless you're programming in Smalltalk anyway :)

Comment: @MattDavey not entirely sure i agree with that application of module. Modules can contain classes, they also already exist in .net.

Comment: @Gusdor it's an ambiguous term, sure, but there are a lot of contexts where the term `module` refers to a logical grouping of standalone functions. The [D language](http://dlang.org/module.html) is an example of this. Even in the .NET space, this can be seen in the [Nemerle](https://github.com/rsdn/nemerle/wiki/CSharp-Similarities-and-Differences) language.

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing object-oriented about the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) class, because object-orientation is about **data with behaviour**, and the Convert class holds no data or state.

It's basically a practical consideration.

In Eiffel, for example, the conversion methods would have been defined in a base class, and all classes needing to use the conversion methods would have derived from that base class. However, Eiffel has multiple inheritance, so that makes sense for Eiffel, but not for a language like C# where you don't have multiple inheritance.

Comment: I think that the point that the `Convert` class is essentially stateless is the most important in this discussion

Answer (score 5):

Your thought is correct. `Convert` is a static utility class, with one purpose - converting between different types.

It has only methods (verbs), which all of them are conversions - so, for readability, it's better  to give the name of the common verb to the class itself, than to repeat it in every method:

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(value);
float f = Convet.ToSingle(value);
```

are much more fluent and readable than:

```
int i = Conversions.ConvertToInt32(value);
float f = Conversions.ConvertToSingle(value);
```

Comment: Any advantage of that over putting the method in the destination type, e.g. `Int32.From(wholenumber)`, `Int32.RoundEven(number)`, `Int32.Trunc(number)`, `Int32.Floor(number)`, or `Int32.RoundPeriodic(number)`?

Comment: The `Convert` class is for conversions, not for flouring (those are in `Math` class). Those type do have conversions on them (`X.Parse(string)`/`X.TryParse(string, out X)` and castings from different types. The `Convert` class treats nulls differently (returning the default value instead of throwing exception), and do overflow checks (by default, overflow checks are turned off).

Comment: An attempt to convert a `Double` value 123.4 to an `Int32` must either fail (throw an exception) or select via some means an integer which isn't equal to the original number.  I would guess that more than half of the places where a `Double` is rounded, it's immediately converted to `Int32` or `Int64`, so combining the two operations into a single step makes sense; Java's approach of having `Double.round` return `long` and `Float.round` return `int` seems far less clear than having the operations in the destination type.

Comment: It's pretty common to just truncate the fracture from the double when casting/converting to an integer. It's even logical - because you can alway cast (implicitly) from small type to a bigger one, but in the other way around, you have to cast explicitly, or convert it to the smaller type. The `Math.Raound` can round to any digit after the decimal point - so it returns the type which it have gotten.

Comment: As it happens, `Convert.ToInt64(Double)` performs round-to-even (I'd forgotten that), but I don't know that people who didn't either test it or explicitly check the documentation would be likely to expect that.  If one views the purpose of e.g. an `Int32.Floor()` method as "return the highest `Int32` which is no greater than the operand", such a method would be more strongly associated with `Int32` than with any other class, and no less strongly than `Int32.Parse` (which only works on strings)

Comment: It performs round-to-even only if the fracture is exactly 0.5... otherwise it's converting to the nearest integer (not to the even). A cast doesn't do any rounding (just truncating the fracture). I'm not sure I understate what you mean by _If one views the purpose of e.g. an Int32.Floor() method as "return the highest Int32 which is no greater than the operand", such a method would be more strongly associated with Int32 than with any other class, and no less strongly than Int32.Parse_ ... What you're describing is what happen when you cast a floating point type to an integer.

Comment: Casting a float -1.75 to integer would yield -1; the floor would be -2.  In any case, my point is that the only floating-point values where the logical meaning of "convert to integer" is unambiguous are those whose fractional part is zero; there are a number of ways via which one may wish to produce an integer from a `float`, `double`, or `Decimal`, and I would think having each number type have its own "produce this type from something else somehow" methods would be cleaner than having a `Convert` class with an NxN set of methods from N types to N types.

Comment: About flouring - I stand corrected, but about a set of methods for each type - I disagree. I actually find it much more cleaner to put those methods in an appropriate utility class (`Math` and `Convert`). The most simple conversion, is the one that used in the cast (which indeed resides in each type). Any other conversion has some meaning which is implied from the class and method which does it.

Answer (score 4):

My personal opinion is that is OK for Convert class to be called after action, because it's a static class, and will not be instanced.

It simply sounds better to call

```
Convert.ToBoolean(var);
```

instead of

```
Converter.ConvertToBoolean(var);
```

Answer (score 4):

Naming conventions are funny beasts. The most important thing is consistency across a framework.

Needless to say, OO conventions can real help architecture legibility. In this case, the convert class and its static methods are *best attempt* replacements for global functions using c# and are given a *fluid* names to indicate as such.

> Convert [parameter] to Int32
>
> Convert [parameter] to Single

By naming them as actions, not objects, we also communicate functional purity.

This is often seen in the singleton pattern as well with the `Instance` property.